# How to analyze IoTHub metered messages metrics in detail

Tags: azure, analytics, metrics, azure-iot-hub

In my current Azure IoT hub solution, I'm using D2C/C2D messages, device twins and file upload.
I had a look at my total metered messages per day (`dailyMessageQuotaUsed`) and was a bit surprised, because the numbers were higher than expected (~10k per day).

[image]

Then I had a look at my d2c/c2d messages (~100-350 per day)

[image]

And my device twin reads/writes from device (~500 per day)

[image]

And my file uploads (~4k per day)

[image]

Query used:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "IOTHUBS" and Category == "FileUploadOperations"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| extend p=parse_json(properties_s) 
| where p.fileUploadStatusCode == 201
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)
```

My assumption now is:

```
2 messages per file upload (initiate, finished)
+ 2 messages per twin operation (request/response)
+ d2c/c2d messages
=> 2*4500 + 2*500 + 300 = 10300
```

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Is there a built-in feature that allows me to see the total metered messages split by their message type (d2c/c2d/twin/file/...) or is my approach the best one possible?
3. Are the `d2c.telemetry.ingress.success` and `c2d.commands.egress.complete.success` metrics the number of metered messages (per 4k) or sent messages (per send)? I couldn't figure it out while reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my assumption correct?

Is partially correct.

> 2 messages per file upload (initiate, finished)

This is correct and aligns with Pricing Documentation:

> Only the messages which initiate a new upload and provide notification of a completed upload count against the daily allotment of messages... in a typical file upload scenario, there are only two messages...

Ref: [Azure IoT Hub pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/)

> + 2 messages per twin operation (request/response)

It depends. Not always will be 2 messages count. Twin reads, writes, and queries are metered in 4-KB chunks.

> + d2c/c2d messages

Only if they are sent separately and you are not using Batching to merge information from multiple messages into a single batch of messages. See [Benefits of using the Azure IoT SDKs, and pitfalls to avoid if you don’t](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/benefits-of-using-the-azure-iot-sdks-in-your-azure-iot-solution/) to learn how to use Batching out-of-the-box when using azure iot sdks.

> Is there a built-in feature that allows me to see the total metered messages split by their message type (d2c/c2d/twin/file/...) or is my approach the best one possible?

Your approach looks to be the most accurate one as of today.

> Are the d2c.telemetry.ingress.success and c2d.commands.egress.complete.success metrics the number of metered messages (per 4k) or sent messages (per send)?

Those metrics represent number of 4k messages sent\received.